# How do i test function (getPermissions) in jest and react where branch and statements are not covered

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
const ProductsCard = ({
  header,
  isNew,
  companyId
}) => (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} className="p-0">
          {getPermissions(companyId, header, isNew)}
        </Col>
      </Row>
);

const getPermissions = (companyId, header, isNew) => {
  let content = null;
  switch (header) {
    case 'one':    //branch not covered
      content = (    //statement not covered
        <ComponentOne/>
      );
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return content;
};

const getShortName = name => {
      if (o === o.toUpperCase()) { // not covered.
        return o;
      }
};

export default ProductsCard;
```

How do i test this branch and statement which are not covered.
Also i need to check if statement inside getShortName() which is not covered.

I am using jest for this but am a beginner .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far to make this work? Where is your Jest code? And where did you fail?

Comment: i dont have any code.

Comment: Well, we are not a code writing service. Try to solve it yourself, then come back with specific issues.